# Sample Bootstrap data table duplicating in nuxt app

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js

I've recently made a new nuxt app with `npx create-nuxt-app` and selected bootstrap as ui and axios as another plugin. I took a sample data table from bootstraps website and when I view the page the table is on the table is duplicating. I've also created a codepen sandbox and the issue is the same. Has anyone experienced this issue?

Sandbox link
https://7wo3jr51.sse.codesandbox.io/Table

Data-table

```
    <template>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container">
    <h2>Bordered Table</h2>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>

    </template>

    <script>
    export default {

    }
    </script>

    <style>

    </style>
```

Comment: Are you recursively nesting a template? It seems you've got a new <html> tag inside your container, suggesting it's loading the whole page inside of that div before your table

Comment: @CarlosReyes I do have a navbar added in my layouts folder but that should have no issue really. In the code sandbox link the issue is the same which is strange. which <html> tag is the new type in the document above so I can remove or replace to test?